# Pass multiple functions as a single prop using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data from child component to parent component. To achieve this, I have to pass methods to child component using which prop values will be sent back to parent.

```
<ChildComponent userData={fetchedData} method1Data={function1} method2Data = {function2}/>}
```

This works fine but I would like to pass both function1 and function2 under same method1Data. As the data sent from child component is same but the usage in both functions is different. Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
<ChildComponent userData={fetchedData} method1Data={function1, function2}/>}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I pass multiple functions as same prop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but need to change it slightly.

something like :

```
  <ChildComponent userData={fetchedData} method1Data={{function1, function2}}/>}
```

then in the child component you will receive a prop `method1Data` which will point to two methods.
you can extract them as follows :

```
const {function1, function2} = props.method1Data;
```

here is a demo :

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j7wsma?file=src/App.js)